# What does this lapel pin signify?

Tags: identification

Metal with painted areas. Center area has an insignia. I have checked online at several places with no luck.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR0Iz.jpg

Palm sized. Gold sunburst cross 0°. Superimposed gold edged blue Maltese cross 45°. Super imposed gold edged white 8 pointed star 0°. Super imposed shield with three bumps at top and three bumps at base dark green. Shield contains: Doubled rounded cross gold centre with two fleurs gold flanking. Crowned with gold crown with club ended points.

Comment: Hi Suzanne and welcome. Nice description!  Anything on the back?

Comment: I see a couple of similar pendants online, but with some differences -- the pendant is ringed, the Maltese cross is at 0º, and the white part is round and not starred. Neither one offers any explanation though. https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/vtg-maltese-cross-coat-arms-pendant-429133734 and https://www.ebay.com/itm/123908145086 if you want to compare.

Comment: Didn't see anything at https://tioh.army.mil/Search.aspx

Comment: The cross of Lorraine? and fleur-de-lys make me think it might be French, but otherwise I have no idea.

Comment: Cross of Lorraine bottony (buttoned)

Comment: IF the central charge were a sword, I would say it was like Jean of Arc posthumous coat of arms but with Vert and Argent instead of Azure and Gold. https://saint-joan-of-arc.com/coat-of-arms.htm https://www.ancient.eu/image/8662/coat-of-arms-of-joan-of-arc/  Would it be french? A french herald would see the closeness to Jean's arms.

Comment: A wild guess: If the central charge is a Loraine cross, it may have something to do with Free France, with the symbolism of having arms similar to St. Jean of Arc (savior of france). It is noticeable that the fleurs the lys appear vertically streched, so the central charge could be a cross of Lorraine.

Comment: and notice that the examples found by shoover are Azure and Gold, like St. Jean.