# Can you identify this Empire flagged c1913 single stack ocean liner?

Tags: 20th-century, identification, naval, canada, migration

I believe my great-grandparents arrived on this ship in 1913. I cannot find the name of the ship.
The family immigrated to Canada in 1913 from Belgium. They may have arrived in Quebec, or Saint John, or Halifax, not certain. However they did make a return trip to Belgium in 1923, and I wonder if this photo dates from that time. There is nothing written on the back of the photo unfortunately.
Can anyone help to ID it?

[image: Two masted one funnel, three deck ship]

Image: Ship. Single stack two masted ocean liner. UK Empire ensign (only union flag quarter identifiable, detailed ensign information unidentifiable: some member of UK Empire’s ensign). Four superstructure decks. Hull decks unidentifiable as portholes below resolution. Length estimated ~170 m.

Comment: Can you post a higher resolution scan of the photograph? There is very little detail visible in this low-res image. Also, please post everything you know about the photo to help narrow the search. In particular anything you know or surmise about when, where, and by whom, even if just educated guesses and identified as such, will assist in the search.

Comment: Where did they arrive? which port? from which country (origin & destination will help to identify potential ships).  Which country ?

Comment: It might be one of the 2 masted 1 funnel ships shown on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_White_Star_Line_ships : the Romanic, the Canopic, the Laurentic, the Megantic, the Zelandic .

Comment: The family immigrated to Canada in 1913 from Belgium. They may have arrived in Quebec, or Saint John, or Halifax, not certain. However they did make a return trip to Belgium in 1923, and I wonder if this photo dates from that time. There is nothing written on the back of the photo unfortunately.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Thanks. Higher res doesn't really help. Still poor quality, photo in poor shape. I added what I know in another comment. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @kimchilover Thank you, I will have a look and see if it might be one of those. Cheers.

Comment: At first I thought that the flag was a horizontal bicolor, dark above and light below.  Looking at it closely, the low stripe might be the sky, and the upper part might have a canton, which would make the flag probably a US flag, a British merchant ensign, or a Canadian red ensign.

Comment: Could you please verbosely visually describe the image.

Comment: @John - all the information should go in the question; you've got a better chance of an answer if you edit the question. I've moved one of your comments in; please add additional information to the question.

Comment: Consider this model of verbose visual description: https://history.stackexchange.com/q/61258/876

Comment: Union quarter in ensign is pretty obvious in the current low quality image.

Comment: Romanic/Scandanavian is route viable for either.  Megantic is route viable for either.  Laurentic is viable for early passage not return.  Canopic is out per routing.  Zealandic is out per routing.

Comment: @SamuelRussell Can you make out the flag at the top of the rear mast?

Comment: Darker top. White centre. Lighter base. Darker and lighter match different colours. Not a match for white star flag. Possible march for Allen line red over blue superimposed white six point with gap between points at 0°. Allen line has passenger manifests online apparently and Scandinavian was running passengers to Canada.

Comment: https://www.bac-lac.gc.ca/eng/discover/immigration/immigration-records/passenger-lists/passenger-lists-1865-1922/Pages/list.aspx?ShipName=Scandinavian&Year=1913&ShippingLine=Allan&

Comment: @SamuelRussell The paintwork on the funnel does not match that of the Allan line (as seen on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMS_Empress_of_France_(1913) for example, but does, I think, match the White Star line's.  That's what first caught my eye, at any rate.

Comment: I did check white stars commercial flag which appears solid red with a white star. Sisters to the type remained white star and on route. Do you know if white star ran a two colour bisected white centre flag?